# Dynamic FAQ click misfiring

Tags: jquery

I'm doing this example from the book *JavaScript and jQuery: The Missing Manual*, where we build a dynamic FAQ section. The idea is that when you click on a question, the answer appears, and if you click on the question again, the answer disappears. My problem is that at times I'm having having to click twice on the questions to make the answer appear/disappear. It's as if the click event is not firing at random.

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>A One Page Faq</title>
<link href="../_css/site.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="../_js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
h2 {
    background: url(../_images/open.png) no-repeat 0 11px;
    padding: 10px 0 0 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
h2.close {
    background-image: url(../_images/close.png);
}

.answer {
    margin-left: 25px;  
}
</style>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.answer').fadeOut(1);
  var hidden = true;

  $('.main h2').click(function() {
        if (hidden) {
            $(this).next('.answer').fadeIn();
            hidden = false;
        }
        else {
            $(this).next('.answer').fadeOut();
            hidden = true;
        }
    });

}); // end ready
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="header">
    <p class="logo">JavaScript <i>&</i> jQuery <i class="mm">The<br>Missing<br>Manual</i></p>
</div>
<div class="content">
<div class="main">
<h1>A One Page FAQ</h1>
<h2>I've heard that JavaScript is the long-lost fountain of youth. Is this true?</h2>
  <div class="answer">
  <p>Why, yes it is! Studies prove that learning JavaScript freshens the mind and extends life span by several hundred years. (Note: some scientists disagree with these claims.)</p>
  </div>
<h2>Can JavaScript really solve all of my problems?</h2>
  <div class="answer">
  <p>Why, yes it can! It's the most versatile programming language ever created and is trained to provide financial management advice, life-saving CPR, and even to take care of household pets.</p>
  </div>
<h2>Is there nothing JavaScript <em>can&#8217;t</em> do?</h2>
  <div class="answer">
  <p>Why, no there isn&#8217;t! It&#8217;s even able to write its own public relations-oriented Frequently Asked Questions pages. Now that&#8217;s one smart programming language!</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/wUTaS/

Comment: Try jumping between questions in a sequence: 1 2 3 2 1 2 3 2 1 etc. (single click each time).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are using one hidden flag for each answer... And so when you click a question, it sets the flag, and then when you click another one, you first have to switch the flag, then it will work as expected on the second click.

Can improve it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.answer').hide();


  $('.main h2').click(function() {
            $(this).next('.answer').slideToggle();
    });

}); // end ready
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wUTaS/1/

Comment: Thanks. I get it now! Ideally I should have used a separate variable for each element, or use the better solution: `slideToggle()`!

Answer (score 0):

use following code,see commenting also

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.answer').hide(); //on page load ...all answers will hide

  $('.main h2').click(function()//when you click on any question 
    { 

            $(this).next('.answer').toggle();//answer will hide /show



        });


}); // end ready
</script>
```